# How to preserve type information when assigning object literal to a type?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following type:

```
type Foo = {
    foo?: number[]
    bar?: number[]
}
```

If I assign `foo` in a literal and assign it to a variable of type `Foo`, it will lose the literal type:

```
const foo1: Foo = {
    foo: []
}
foo1.foo.push(3) // Error: foo1.foo is possibly undefined
```

But TS is clearly capable of following optional properties:

```
const foo2: Foo = {}
foo2.foo = []
foo2.foo.push(3) // OK
```

One solution would be to use `satisfies` operator, but it has other issues:

```
const foo3 = {
    foo: []
} satisfies Foo
foo3.foo.push(3) // OK
foo3.bar = [] // But this now fails
```

Is there any way to have TS recognize optional properties assigned in the literal, instead of starting from scratch as soon as it is assigned to a variable?

Comment: If you're not happy with how `satisfies` works you can fall back to what we had to do before it existed: write a helper function to guide inference.  [Here](https://tsplay.dev/N5j4dm) is one approach.  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to clarify the use case.

Comment: How would you extend that to nested objects containing more optional properties?

Comment: Just an outsider's opinion, but given `Foo` is defined as having an optional prop, you're probably best off respecting that interface and coding to it accordingly even if you're absolutely sure that the optional property has a value. Any other part of your code that receives a `Foo` has to treat its properties as optional, so you're simply looking for some special case where they're treated as non-optional immediately after assignment. Doesn't seem like a good idea to me. You can eliminate the error simply by using the optional chaining operator and changing nothing else: `foo1.foo?.push(3)`

Comment: @riv Probably write some kind of ugly recursive mapped type and maybe even use type assertions.  I'd need to see a [mre] in the question, to have a concrete answer.

Comment: @riv, when you get a chance, let me know whether I should write up my suggestion as an answer or if you want to [edit] to show a more representative use case.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a wrapper that will:

- keep the known properties from the literal
- and have the optional properties of the base type

For example:

```js
function constant<T>(x: T){
  return {
    satisfies<B extends T extends B ? unknown : never>(){
      return x as T & B
    }
  }
}
```

With this wrapper, the examples in the question work:

```js
const foo4 = constant({
    foo: []
}).satisfies<Foo>()

foo4.foo.push(3)
foo4.bar = []

const foo5 = constant({}).satisfies<Foo>()

foo5.foo = []
foo5.foo.push(3)
foo5.bar = []
```